# Android | JAVA | How to add a shadow to vector?

Tags: android, imageview, shadow, android-vectordrawable

I have a svg vector file. How can I add **colored shadow** to it. I did research on google and stackoverflow but, looks like It's not working in my case.

**SVG XML**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:viewportWidth="35"
    android:viewportHeight="35">
  <path
      android:pathData="M18.5,18.5m-12.5,0a12.5,12.5 0,1 1,25 0a12.5,12.5 0,1 1,-25 0"
      android:fillColor="@color/green"/>
</vector>
```

code inside
**activity_main.xml**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/green"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_green_light" />
```

I can't find a simple or even a working way to add shadow to it.

I want to add a shadow like this..
[image: Reference image]

**Note : Elevation on ImageView is not working.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the shadow works for vectors. It's probably complex to calculate all shadows that are being cast. Instead, you should create a background in the shape of your shadow:

*drawable/background.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/green" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**1) Elevation**

When using elevation, Android will render the shadow automatically.
`android:elevation="16dp` on your `ImageView` should do the trick.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/green"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_green_light" />
```

**NOTE:**

The *higher* the elevation, the bigger and more blurred the shadow will be.

Using a *lower* elevation, will result in a smaller but more crip shadow.

For controlling the color, you can use these on API28+:

```
android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="#ff0000" // api 28+ only
android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#ff0000" // api 28+ only
```

**2) Shadow**

Another option, is to use:

```
android:shadowColor="@color/almost_black"
android:shadowDx="1.5f"
android:shadowDy="1.5f"
android:shadowRadius="12f"
```

for a bit more control. But that probably requires a TextView.

**3) Change the Vector**

If all this fails, you should consider creating the shadow yourself as part of the Vector

Comment: where do i put these ```android:shadowColor ="@color/almost_black"``` these options ? it seems to be found nowhere. Not inside my vector, not inside any shape xml nor in imageview.